# How to add a pulsating animation to the data point on a line chart using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As mentioned in the question I am using the library Charts.js. In my case I want to create a line chart. The line chart has some data points which I want to highlight by giving them an animation.

Please see the following example for my upcoming question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myLineChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    // Sample data for the line chart
    var data = {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Sample Data',
        data: [10, 25, 18, 30, 15],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        fill: true,
      }]
    };

    // Configuration options
    var options = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'category',
          labels: data.labels,
        },
      }
    };

    // Get the canvas element
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart').getContext('2d');

    // Create the line chart
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, how is it possible to animate the data point x = February, y = 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterInit` hook for updating your chart on a regular interval. To do so, use the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function. Make sure to use chart [update mode `'none'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#update-mode) to skips Chart.js default animation.

```
afterInit: chart => setInterval(() => { 
  const pointRadius = chart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius;
  pointRadius[1] = pointRadius[1] == r ? rAccent : r;
  chart.update('none');
}, 500)
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const r = 3;
const rAccent = 8;
new Chart('myLineChart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterInit: chart => setInterval(() => { 
      const pointRadius = chart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius;
      pointRadius[1] = pointRadius[1] == r ? rAccent : r;
      chart.update('none');
    }, 500)
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Sample Data',
      data: [10, 25, 18, 30, 15],
      borderColor: ['blue', 'red','blue','blue','blue'],
      pointRadius: [r, r, r, r, r],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
      fill: true,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myLineChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's it. But actually I expected a solution like in css to make a more smooth transition.

Answer (score 1):

For a smooth transition, chartsJS allows you to use animations, as explained [here in the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html). They can even be customised for different properties of each data point!

So far, however, I have not been able to get the animation to work without hovering over the point. Perhaps you'll be able to figure that out.

For instance, you could have the animations as an array, one animation for each point.

```js
animations: [
  {},
  {
  backgroundColor: {
    type: 'color',
    duration: 100,
    easing: 'linear',
    from: 'rgba(10,10,10,0.5)',
    to: 'rgba(200,100,100,0.5)',
    loop: true
  },
  radius: {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
    from: 10,
    to: 50,
    loop: true,
    delay: 10
  }
},
{},{},{}
]
```

I added the animations for backgroundColor and radius to only the point in question. You could do this for any of the points.

Here's your code with the animations added.

Like I mentioned earlier, you have to hover over the point to get the animation started. There should be a solution to this, but I haven't found that yet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myLineChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    // Sample data for the line chart
    var data = {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Sample Data',
        data: [10, 25, 18, 30, 15],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        fill: true,
        animations: [
          {},
          {
          backgroundColor: {
            type: 'color',
            duration: 100,
            easing: 'linear',
            from: 'rgba(10,10,10,0.5)',
            to: 'rgba(200,100,100,0.5)',
            loop: true
          },
          radius: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'linear',
            from: 10,
            to: 50,
            loop: true,
            delay: 10
          }
        },
        {},{},{}
        ]
      }]
    };

    // Configuration options
    var options = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'category',
          labels: data.labels,
        },
      }
    };

    // Get the canvas element
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart').getContext('2d');

    // Create the line chart
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```